# file:///usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/TextFieldStyle.qml:142: TypeError: Cannot read property of null. How to solve this?

Tags: qt, qml

This is the code

```
TextField {
    id: textField
    menu: null

    property color activeColor   : Properties.textField.enabledColor
    property color deactiveColor : Properties.textField.disabledColor
    property bool convertToUCase : false;
    property int closeImageSize: 26
    property int renderType: Text.QtRendering

    style: Style.textFieldStyle

    onTextChanged: {
        text = (convertToUCase) ? text.toUpperCase() : text;
    }
}
```

I want to remove this warning in the console output. How can we I this? I tried many ways to solve this. The connection between the textFieldStyle qml should have some problem. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This cut of code looks wrong. Show more code. Show what "textfield" is. there is no standard controls named "textfield" is this custom one? Show your real code if youu need help

Comment: added textfield.  textFieldStyle is a qml type

Comment: Which line is 142 of TextFieldStyle.qml in this code?

Comment: property control panel :item{